# Why are all contact birthdays one day off in a Windows Phone 8.1 C# WinRT app?

Tags: c#, date, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am pulling contact data from the People app.  Then I display the various contact data fields in a Grid in my app.  Everything works great except for the dates of contact's birthdays are always showing up as one day too soon.

I don't know what time zone the Microsoft Windows Phone 8.1 People Hub app uses, but my phone is set to (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, etc.

If I enter a contact's birthday as 2015/01/02 in the People app, when I run my app, it returns the date as 2015/01/01.

Can someone please explain why this is and how to fix it?

Here is an example:

```
        var store = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
        var contacts = await store.FindContactsAsync();

        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            foreach (var date in contact.ImportantDates)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("day: " + date.Day);
                // expected: day: 02
                // result: day: 01
            }
        }
```

EDIT: additional information

If I change the time zone on my phone, or in the emulator, to (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada), then the dates do appear correctly in my app.  It does seem to be related to the phone's time zone...

Comment: Did you debug your code and see your `date` is really `2015/01/02`?

Comment: @Soner Gönül Yes.  If I add `Debug.WriteLine(date.ToString());` then it produces:
Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactDate,
and if I add `Debug.WriteLine(date.Year + "/" + date.Month + "/" + date.Day);`
it produces: 2015/1/1